# Akka-Http with SQL queries how to do it without slick?

Tags: mysql, scala, akka-http

I want to use MySQL queries with Akka-Http. I tried with Slick but don't want to use slick. I want to achieve the goal just using SQL queries

Comment: You can do [plain SQL](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/sql.html) with Slick, so can you explain why you have rejected this option?

Comment: Actually @Tim I'm new to scala-akka so I have no idea how to do with it so that's why

Comment: Ah, OK :) Have a look at the docs and come back here if you have any problems!

Comment: @Tim do you have any project reference for much better understanding?

Comment: @Tim If you have any reference for without slick in simple queries

Comment: In addition to @Tim 's comment, there are also so many other libraries you can use to connect to your database, so you can choose whatever you want, google "ORM libraries Scala", "FRM libraries Scala", or take a look at this blogpost on [softwaremill](https://softwaremill.com/comparing-scala-relational-database-access-libraries/)

Comment: @AminMal bruh do you have Plain Queries ka example actually i have got some work in plain SQL queries. Using slick schema i did but now i have to use plain quries using mysql java connector

Comment: @Tim how to create tables n all in plain sql queries. I'm not understanding anything regards to that

Comment: @AnilSingh well try to illustrate your question in a better manner! "Akka-Http with SQL queries how to do it without slick?" doesn't necessarily mean using raw queries, and also, the term `using SQL queries` doesn't necessarily mean raw and literal string queries!

Comment: @AminMal Actually i have to use MySQL database using JDBC using Scala language and Akka-http